# c# LINQ DataTable substraction

Tags: linq, datatable

i have two DataTables which has different columns but one column is same.

i want to get new DataTable which contains row from dt1 which are not exist in dt2.

how can i do it using LINQ?

that's is my current code, but it work only for Datatables with same columns:

```
private void Delete_HPM_Deleted_Points(int YellowCard_Request_ID)
{
    DataTable dt_hpm_points_DB = DataAccessLayer.Get_YellowCard_Request_HPM_Points(YellowCard_Request_ID);
    //dt_hpm_points_DB.Columns.Remove("HPM_Tool_ID");
    //dt_hpm_points_DB.Columns.Remove("HPM_Point_Message");
    //dt_hpm_points_DB.Columns.Remove("HPM_Point_isDisabled");
    //dt_hpm_points_DB.Columns.Remove("HPM_Point_Comments");

    DataTable dt_hpm_points_Local = UserSession.Get_User_YC_HPM_Added_Points_DATATABLE();
    //dt_hpm_points_Local.Columns.Remove("HPM_Tool_ID");
    //dt_hpm_points_Local.Columns.Remove("HPM_Point_Message");

    //var rowsInFirstNotInSecond = dt_hpm_points_DB.Rows.Where(r1 => !dt_hpm_points_Local.Rows.Any(r2 => r1.ID == r2.ID));

    DataTable dt_points_to_remove = dt_hpm_points_DB.AsEnumerable().Except(dt_hpm_points_Local.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default).CopyToDataTable();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt_points_to_remove.Rows)
    {
        DataAccessLayer.Delete_YellowCard_Request_HPM_Point(YellowCard_Request_ID, dr["HPM_Point_ID"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Linq-To-DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb552415.aspx) with a "Left Outer Join":

```
var justInDT1 = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                on r1.Field<int>("PK_ID") equals r2.Field<int>("FK_ID") into GJ
                from subRow in GJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where subRow == null
                select r1;
```

[**How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: If you want a new `DataTable` from the result use `justInDT1.CopyToDataTable()`